# In Anylogic, how to model an agent which has agent of type A which has agents of type B, agent of type B has agents of type C inside it

Tags: anylogic

A big container has 100 open boxes in a row, and each box has 3 items in it. There is a trolley which picks up items in a specific box(say based on its Id) one by one and drops them at another location and then goes to another box and so on. Basically, the trolley has the order in which it has to pick boxes.

I am new to anylogic. I might be having wrong thinking, but here is my idea.
I thought of modelling Big container as one agent type, Box as another agent type, item as another agent type and create a collection of 3 items in box agent, collection of 100 boxes in big container agent. Is this a right way to model? Also, I am not knowing how to animate the big container with boxes which have items in it.

Please let me know if there are any ideas on how to model this scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

correct approach, I would say.
To embed Agent B into Agent A, open Agent A and drag in Agent B from the "Projects" view. That creates a population of B within A. Set its properties accordingly (i.e. the number of B's in A...)

Re animation: You need to understand relative coordinates with embedded agents. Play around with adding an image to A, B and C at their center coordinates and check out how it looks at runtime (it will be all on top of each other).

Then, experiment with changing the location to see the impact. AnyLogic help also has good explanations how it works.